# How to convert NSDate to german Date?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one iphone application in which I want to convert NSDate to NSString but in german format.

Can you give me some idea about that.

I am using below code.

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[eventInfo valueForKey:@"startdat"] intValue]];

//2011-05-01 21:04:00 +0000(I am geeting this date)

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *nl_NL = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];

        [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"E,dd MMM yyyy"];
    [formatter1 setLocale:nl_NL];

    NSString *stringFromDate1 = [formatter1 stringFromDate:date];
    [formatter1 release];
    [nl_NL release];
```

//I am getting stringFromDate1 = "Mo.,02 Mai 2011" value.(wrong output)

Please give me idea

Comment: nl_NL = Dutch, but you assign it the German locale?

Comment: @dreamlax, I agree, local should be de_DE = Deutsch, i.e. German I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use for example

```
[formatter1 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
```

instead of `setDateFormat:`.

Comment: But this give me wrong output my NSDate is different compare to output string

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the time zone is taken into account when the NSDateFormatter is formatting the date. If you want the NSDateFormatter to format the exact same date as the NSLog'd version, you need to explicitly set the time zone of the formatter.

```
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"E,dd MMM yyyy"];
[formatter1 setLocale:nl_NL];
[formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure (from your question), what is your expected output. But assuming that you are looking for the full day of week description, try this date format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
```

It gives the output:

Sonntag, 01 Mai 2011     (using de_DE locale)

---

In general, the number of characters determine the size of date field:

eg. Input date = 2011-05-01 Sunday

1-character = 1-digit/character number or word (if number/word can't be 1 character long then abbreviation or fullname is displayed).

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, d M y"];  // Sun, 1 5 2011
```

2-character = 2-digit/character number or word (if number/word can't be 2 character long then abbreviation is displayed).

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE, dd MM yy"];  // Sun, 01 05 11
```

3-character = 3-digit/character number or word, or abbreviation (generally).

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, ddd MMM yyy"];  // Sun, 001 May 2011
```

4-character = full name (generally).

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dddd MMMM yyyy"];  // Sunday, 0001 May 2011
```

Here's the weird part though, if you specify 5 E's, you get an rather unexpected output:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEEE, ddddd MMMMM yyyyy"];  // S, 00001 M 2011
```

For date formatting, I find the the following reference table very useful.
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

Good luck

Comment: The problem is not the format of the date, but the fact that although his NSDate object shows the 1st of May 2011, his formatted date shows the **2nd** of May.

Comment: Reread the original code and saw the problem. Your solution may work because an NSDate object is initialized with the user's current timezone (which may not be set to Europe Central Time or GMT as indicated on the input string). Setting the timezone to the correct one may resolve the problem. Cheers.